# GCC link error when using my own local version of printf for embedded system

Tags: gcc

I have a local version of sprintf and printf1 in a file called small_printf.c. Works fine, writing debug messages to a serial port (messages viewed with minicom). Sure is a lot better than using the four line LCD display on my microcontroller board debugging a RTOS.

The issue is that when I rename printf1 to printf throughout the source code I get the following error. Apparently the options "nostdlib" & "nodefaultlibs" do not do what I expected. Why I don't see a problem with the "sprintf" name is puzzling, only with "printf".

I looked around a bit to see if this was answered anywhere, and the best answer was to update to a newer version of gcc.

```
Linking: image.elf
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mthumb start.o main_uart.o mam.o sc.o led.o keypad.o timer.o delay.o small_printf.o rtc.o lcd.o uart.o interrupt.o --output image.elf -T./lpc2132.ld -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -nostdlib -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,-Map=image.map,--cref

`.rodata.str1.4' referenced in section `.text' of /usr/local/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/libc.a(lib_a-puts.o): defined in discarded section `.rodata.str1.4' of /usr/local/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/libc.a(lib_a-puts.o)

`.rodata.str1.4' referenced in section `.text' of /usr/local/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/libc.a(lib_a-syscalls.o): defined in discarded section `.rodata.str1.4' of /usr/local/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/libc.a(lib_a-syscalls.o)
```

I am using GCC version 6.3, binutils 2.27, newlib 2.5.0. Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCC most probly optimizes call to `printf` to `puts` if there are no format specifiers. To avoid this, add `-fno-builtin-printf` to your `CFLAGS`.

Comment: CFLAGS += -fno-builtin-printf is what I added to the Makefile. Great! Thank you...

Comment: @rsun Glad to help. If the answer had been useful, you might consider +1'ing it

Comment: I just discovered that the built object is built with libc.a puts along with a lot of other routines in libc.a. Not what I wanted for a embedded flash microcontroller. I still could call my local print --> "small_printf". But I like to learn what is going on.

Comment: @rsun So `-fno-builtin` didn't help to get rid of `puts`? You can then implement `puts` yourself (redirect it to your implementation of `printf`).

Comment: yugr, I went back to check this. IT DID WORK. I thought I had double checked the result before adding the last comment. That's what happens when I juggle two projects with five Makefiles at once.